# Comparar elementos de un arreglo

Tags: javascript

Como puedo comparar una variable con todos y cada uno de los elementos de un arreglo

```
var saludo = ["hi", "hola", "buenos dias", "buen dia"];
if(otraVariableX == saludo[]) { 
    alert("Hola!!!"); 
}
```

solo me funciona el `if` si especifico la posiciones del array ejemplo:

```
saludo[0]
saludo[1]
```

Pero quiero que se compare con todos los elementos del arreglo, 4 en este caso *saludo[0-3]*

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta no es del todo clara ya que no se mencionan posibles casos, por ejemplo, ¿tu arreglo puede tener elementos con valores repetidos? Por otro lado, ¿qué vas a hacer con el resultado? ¿es relevante saber en que posición se encuentran las coincidencias o sólo si el elemento buscado está incluido en el arreglo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar un for para recorrer todo el arreglo e ir comparando.

```js
 saludo =["hi", "hola", "buenos dias", "buen dia"];
 otraVariableX = "hola";

for (var i = 0; i < saludo.length; i++) {

  if (otraVariableX == saludo[i]) {
    alert("Hola!!!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Aquí te dejo algunas formas para verificar tu duda:

```
saludo.some(function(el){  return el === "hola"}); // si alguno cumple esta condición 
//output = true

saludo.includes("hola");  //true o false si existe o no
//output = true

saludo.indexOf("hola"); // si es mayor a -1 existe y retorna su posición 
//output = 1

var res = false; 
saludo.forEach(function(el){
   if(el === "hola") res = true;    
});

console.log(res); //output = true
```

Answer (score 3):

Los `Arrays` poseen en un método [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes) , para saber si un elemento está contenido en un `Array` , devolverá un valor `booleano` , `TRUE` si se encuentra caso contrario `FALSE`.

```js
var saludo = ["hi", "hola", "buenos dias", "buen dia"];

if(saludo.includes("hola"))
  console.log("Si se encuentra");
else
  console.log("No Se encuentra ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Una manera puede ser recorrer el arrays con [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in), o bien con el método [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split), en el siguiente ejemplo te ilustro las 2 maneras (entre otras):

```js
var saludo = ["hi", "hola", "buenos dias", "buen dia"];
var otraVariableX = prompt("ingresa un saludo");

// Ejemplo con: for..in
for (n in saludo) {
 if (otraVariableX == saludo[n]) {
  alert("Hola!!! for..in");
 }
}
// Ejemplo con: el método join()
if (saludo.join(" ").indexOf(otraVariableX)+1) {
 alert("Hola!!! join()");
}
```